# PHP POST requests only inserts blank rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So i'm pretty new to PHP and can't understand why my POST request is not working. .

I'm just building a simple TodoApp and have a Add new task view like this:
add.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
    
        <title>To-Do List</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
    
            <form action="" method="post">
                <h2 class="title">Add a new task</h2>
    
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="inputFields">
    
                        <label for="task">Task:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="Task name" />
    
                        <label for="task">Description:</label>
                        <br />
                        <textarea type="text" name="description" placeholder="Add a description"  rows="5"
                            cols="40"></textarea>
                        <br />
    
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
    
            <a href="../index.php"><button class="btn">Go back</button></a>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My db file DB.php looks like this:

```
<?php

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);  

/**
 * @package DBConnection
 * @author Frida
 */

// DB Connection
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=TodoApp', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// GET - Get All tasks
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM todo_list ORDER BY created DESC');
$statement->execute();
// Fetch all tasks as an assoc array
$tasks = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

 // POST - Add a task

$task = $_POST['task'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO todo_list (task, description, status, created)
VALUES ('$task', '$description', 0, '$date')
") 

?>
```

This is my schema:
[Todo schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX7Cq.png)

I've done var_dump($_POST) which shows the array without any issues, if anyone can help me out?

Comment: <form action="" method="post"> need in action="DB.php"

Comment: Can you please put the output of `var_export($_POST)` in the question?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML form action attribute is empty which mean that form is submit to same file in your case add.php.
So you should use $_POST in add.php file either you must submit form to DB.php for example

```
<form action="DB.php" method="post">
```